# Can one perform a left join in pandas that selects only the first match on the right?

Tags: python, pandas, left-join

Can one perform a left join in pandas that selects only the first match on the right? Example:

```
left            = pd.DataFrame()
left['age']     = [11, 12]
right           = pd.DataFrame()
right['age']    = [10, 11, 11]
right['salary'] = [ 100, 150, 200 ]
left.merge( right, how='left', on='age' )
```

Returns

```
   age  salary
0   11     150
1   11     200
2   12     NaN
```

But what I would like is to preserve the number of rows of left, by merely taking the first match. That is:

```
   age  salary
0   11     150
2   12     NaN
```

So I've been using

```
left.merge( right.drop_duplicates(['age']), how='left', on='age')
```

but I believe this makes a full copy of right. And it smells funny.

Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: This would straightforward to add as an option to ``merge``, but is not implemented at the moment.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I'll request it. Will leave the question here in case somebody can point out to me how to avoid the copy (or side effect) in the interim.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can use groupby to remove your duplicate lines. Do everything you've done to define left and right. Now, I define a new dataframe on your last line:

```
left2=left.merge( right, how='left', on='age' )
df= left2.groupby(['age'])['salary'].first().reset_index()
df
```

At first I used a .min(), which will give you the minimum salary at each age, as such:

```
df= left2.groupby(['age'])['salary'].min().reset_index()
```

But you were specifically asking about the first match. To do so you use the .first() option.  Note: The .reset_index() at the end, just reformats the output of the groupby to be a dataframe again.

Comment: This will only work under the assumption that the key 'age' is unique in *left*, so it works in this example, but not as a general way to do left merges, which should leave the *left* dataframe complete

Comment: @576i I agree. In addition `left2.groupby(['age'])['salary'].first().reset_index()` is just a more convoluted way to do `left2.drop_duplicates(['age'])` as it was proposed by the OP.