# Pandas one-to-one row merge, maintaining the structure on the left hand side?

Tags: python, pandas, merge, drop-duplicates

a similar question to an unresolved SO question ([Can one perform a left join in pandas that selects only the first match on the right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26258996)), but slightly more complex and with no obvious workaround. I am hoping that there may be some fresh functionality or inspiration available.

I have two dataframes and I want to merge in a one-to-one fashion from the top working down, rather than a Cartesian manner. For example:

```
l1=['a','b','c','c']
l2=['001','002','003','004']
l3=['a','a','b','b','c','c','c','c']
l4=['006','007','008','009','010','011','012','013']

dfa=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(l1,l2)),columns=['A1','A2'])
dfb=pd.DataFrame(list(zip(l3,l4)),columns=['B1','B2'])

dfa
Out[968]: 
  A1   A2
0  a  001
1  b  002
2  c  003
3  c  004

dfb
Out[969]: 
  B1   B2
0  a  006
1  a  007
2  b  008
3  b  009
4  c  010
5  c  011
6  c  012
7  c  013
```

My desired outcome once I 'merge' on columns A1 and B1 is that I only end up with 4 rows, with the first instances of each A1 / B1 value joining with each other, and the second instances of each A1 / B1 value joining with each other, and so on :-

```
  A1   A2   B2
0  a  001  006
1  b  002  008
2  c  003  010
3  c  004  011
```

I can't left-merge then groupby and take the first() / head(1), because c in A1 isn't unique. Neither can I drop_duplicates() on B1 in dfb, for the same reason. Beyond that, aside from something complicated using loops, I am out of ideas.

Has anyone got any profound insights they can share?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's try to create a 'key' column with `groupby()`+`cumcount()` to track position then merge on A1,B1 and key:

```
dfa['key']=dfa.groupby(['A1']).cumcount()
dfb['key']=dfb.groupby(['B1']).cumcount()
df=dfa.merge(dfb,left_on=['A1','key'],right_on=['B1','key']).drop(['B1','key'],1)
```

output of `df`:

```
   A1   A2      B2
0   a   001     006
1   b   002     008
2   c   003     010
3   c   004     011
```

Comment: you were too quick, I had the same as one liner with `assign` ;)

Comment: @Anurag Dabas, that has absolutely nailed it, thank you! I'll accept the answer in 2 minutes once I'm allowed to.

Comment: @mozway - thanks for the comment - I'll have a look at assign too.

Comment: OK, I'll post it, but it's really the same with syntactic sugar to avoid having to assign the count separately ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the version with `assign`. It's really working the same as @Anurag Dabas' version

```
(dfa.assign(count=dfa.groupby('A1').transform('cumcount'))
    .merge(dfb.assign(count=dfb.groupby('B1').transform('cumcount')),
           left_on=('A1', 'count'), right_on=('B1', 'count'))
).drop(['count', 'B1'], axis=1)
```